# How to modify source IP for a Pod in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, cloud, iptables, kubernetes-pod, network-security

To change the source IP to 100.101.102.103 for outgoing data to a specific destination, I modified **iptables** inside the container of a Kubernetes Pod by executing iptables CLI tool:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING --destination 100.200.150.50/32 -j SNAT --to-source 100.101.102.103
```

But it blocks my outgoing data to that destination and seems like the data is caught inside the container for example when I send a simple request by Curl and watch it by Tcpdump tool.

The main question can be: How to modify source IP for a Pod in Kubernetes for a destination outside the cluster?

**P.S**. I deployed my pod in privileged mode with **NET_ADMIN** and **NET_RAW** access.

Comment: You want to modify source IP of  the pod to a random IP?

Comment: No. I need it to be a static one configured / passed at deployment time.

Comment: You should not play with networking inside the `pod` because it won't last. Each restart or reschedule and configuration is gone. You can check this [kube-static-egress-ip](https://github.com/nirmata/kube-static-egress-ip).

Comment: @Crou Yes, this is why I'm trying to configure Node's iptable from inside a Pod (in an automated way) so those changes will remain after Node restart or each Pod re-install on any node. For sure I'll think about a graceful cleanup later too. And thanks for the link

Comment: What you're trying to achieve is definitely an anti-pattern in the K8s world. Would you be able to explain the context? There might be another approach to your problem.

Comment: @BernardHalas , I have a destination outside K8 cluster which wants me to have a static IP when I send data to it over network so it can somehow recognize / identify me. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I modified iptables inside the container of a Kubernetes Pod

I suggest not to do this as it may corrupt kubernetes' CNI and/or kube-proxy. Instead, consider using kubernetes egress to have a well-known source IP address in outgoing packets to a destination outside the cluster.

Egress packets from a k8s cluster to a destination outside the cluster have node's IP as the source IP.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/source-ip/ says egress packets from k8s get source NAT'ed with node's IP:

> [Source NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#SNAT): replacing the source IP on a packet, usually with a node’s IP

Following can be used to send egress packets from a k8s cluster:

- [k8s network policies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/)
- [calico CNI egress policies](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.6/security/kubernetes-network-policy#create-egress-policies)
- [istio egress gateway](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-gateway/)
- [nirmata/kube-static-egress-ip GitHub project](https://github.com/nirmata/kube-static-egress-ip)

Comment: Thank you Vikram. It somehow worked this way: a privileged pod like daemonset or a pod with hostNetwork:true excluded the desired destination from the right calico policy (using iptables cli) and then set a new iptables rule, then the main service pod does not need to be privileged. Tricky and fragile.

Comment: Hello LoosingSleep, sorry for resurrecting an old thread. Am in a very similar boat as yours. I need to be able to assign a static ip to my egress traffic coming out of my pod. I was going down the route of modifying the iptables from within the pod to SNAT the private ip to public ip and realized it was very hacky. Can you please elaborate a bit more on how you went about solving this?